# Lithium Luna CLI no connection to Daemon unable to transfer

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, monerod, transfer, lithium-luna

monero-wallet-cli v0.12.0.0 Lithium Luna

OS: Linux 64bit Ubuntu 16.04

Transfer via CLI no longer works.  A couple days ago this worked fine.  I run the `transfer` command.

```
[wallet 4xxxxx]: transfer unimportant 13 4xxxxxx 1
No payment id is included with this transaction. Is this okay?  (Y/Yes/N/No): Y
Error: no connection to daemon. Please make sure daemon is running.
[wallet 4xxxxx]: status
Refreshed 1566204/1566204, synced, daemon RPC v1.19
[wallet 4xxxxx]: status
Refreshed 1566208/1566208, synced, daemon RPC v1.19
```

I see that monerod is running fine on my local machine when executing the `status` command.

What else can I try?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. Just leaving a comment waiting for an answer. Hope this gets fixed.

Comment: @nu everest - Could you try the steps I posted here -> https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/8hd5qh/error_no_connection_to_daemon_please_make_sure/dyjf9lu/

Comment: @deBRUYNE Could you explain why blocks need to be popped and files need to be deleted? I do not like blindly following instructions.

Comment: @nu everest - Pop blocks removes the last 2000 blocks of your blockchain. Subsequently, you can resync them with `monerod`. I posted this suggestions, because it ensures the last 2000 blocks are all valid. In addition, deleting `p2pstate.bin` deletes all records of peers you were connected to or peers that were connected to you. This ensures you don't accidentally connect to a peer that is on the alternative chain. My post may not resolve your issue though, in which case you'll, alas, have to nuke your local blockchain (`data.mdb`) and perform a resync from scratch.

Comment: Same problem on my 3 separate instances of monero, --pop-blocks does not help, nor resync from scratch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to dEBRUYNE.  This is what worked for me.

- Stop monerod
- Delete p2pstate.bin
- Pop the last 8000 blocks (~800 blocks / day)

> ./monero-blockchain-import --data-dir path/to/data/directory --pop-blocks 8000

- Start monerod

> ./monerod

- Start monero wallet CLI

> ./monero-wallet-cli --data-dir path/to/data/directory